# Category JSON listing

Tags: javascript, node.js

I got this categories JSON below as you can see.

```js
let categories = [{
        "title": "Example 1",
        "filter": {
            "type": "version",
            "version": 20
        },
        "items": []
    }, {
        "title": "Example 2",
        "filter": {
            "type": "count",
            "count": 1
        },
        "items": []
    }
]
```

and I have some JSON files in a folder which looks like this below, all of them got the same keys but the values changes for some.

```json
{
  "version": 20,
  "count": 1
}
```

I am trying to find a way to push these JSON names into items of categories by checking the filter object, which looks like this in code:

```js
let folder = fs.readdirSync("./items/")
let categoryindex = 0;

// Loop over folder.
folder.forEach(item => {

    // Loop over all categories.
    categories.forEach(category => {
        if (category.filter) { // If category got filter
            if (category.filter[category.filter.type] == item[category.filter.type]) { // If filter equals item's data.
                categoryindex = categories.indexOf(category) // Set index of the category.
            }
        }
    })
   if (categoryindex >= 0) {
      categories[categoryindex].items.push(item) // Push file's name to items array.
    }
})
```

Some file JSONs might match more than one category's filter check, if so, it should be included in both categories array.

I want to know if there is a better way to do this because some JSON names end up in their right array while some don't or they just don't get pushed at all.

Comment: This confuses me, what exactly are you doing, and what is going wrong?

Comment: Theres this folder of JSON files, all of the JSON files contain the same keys but different values. I am trying to put them in a category JSON by their key value.

Comment: It looks like it isn't allowing anything to be sorted into the first category. I think you should change `categoryindex > 0` to `categoryindex >= 0`, also it is only going to put each object in 1 category

Comment: I don't think thats the issue, it's somewhere with comparing the filter data.

Comment: try it, the answer below addresses this problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you try to match the items type and category filter type and, if the same, push it into category items array. in your code, you have stored the index of the category as a primitive value so it gets replaced by the last updated value so you cannot get all the categories so I addressed the problem by inserting the item while checking for the condition.

```js
let folder = fs.readdirSync("./items/")

folder.forEach(item => {
    categories.forEach(category => {
        if (!category.filter) return;

        let type = category.filter.type;
        if (category.filter[type] === item[type]) {
            category.items.push(item)
          }
    })
})
```

Comment: This could be a solution, if category does not have "filter", it will throw an error on type.

Comment: @jeputier didnt notice that will correct it thanks